# I am practising in snack.expo.io and I am getting this : "Device: (986:2890) The component for route 'componentOne' must be a React component."

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, expo

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { createSwitchNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

const AppNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
  componentOne: ScreenOne,
  componentTwo: ScreenTwo
});

class ScreenOne extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.componentOne}>
        <Button
          title="goto two"
          onPress={this.prop.navigation.navigate('componentTwo')}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class ScreenTwo extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.componentTwo}>
        <Button
          title="goto one"
          onPress={this.prop.navigation.navigate('componentOne')}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <AppNavigator />
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  componentOne: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    border: 10,
    borderColor: 'teal',
  },

  componentTwo: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    border: 10,
    borderColor: 'orange',
  },
})
```

The above code contains two screen(React Component) ScreenOne and ScreenTwo and App to embed AppNavigator.I am getting this issue continuously:
**Device: (986:2890) The component for route 'componentOne' must be a React component**.

Since for practice I am doing all this in one single file.

Comment: the componentOne is a style, not a React component

Comment: Try to consider giving styles and navigator names different (Here the createSwitchNavigator screen names and style names are same `componentOne` and `componentTwo`)